# Create new variable for grouped data using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
d = {'name': ['john', 'john', 'john', 'Tim', 'Tim', 'Tim','Bob', 'Bob'], 'Prod': ['101', '102', '101', '501', '505', '301', '302', '302'],'Qty': ['5', '4', '1', '3', '5', '4', '1', '3']}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data= d)
```

[image]

What I want to do is, create a new id variable. Whenever a name (say john) appears for the first time this id will be equal to 1, for other occurrence of the same name (john) this id variable will be 0. This will be done for all the other names in the data. How do I go about doing that ?

Final output should be like this:

[image]

NOTE: If someone knows SAS, there you can sort your data by the name and then use first.name.

```
       ""if first.variable = 1 then id = 1""
```

For first occurrence of same name first.name = 1. For any other repeat occurrence of same name, first.name = 0. I am trying to replicate the same in python.

So far I have tried pandas groupby and first() functionality and also numpy.where() but couldnt make any of that work. Any fresh perspective will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `cumcount`

```
s=df.groupby(['Prod','name']).cumcount().add(1)
df['counter']=s.mask(s.gt(1),0)
df
Out[1417]: 
  Prod Qty  name  counter
0  101   5  john        1
1  102   4  john        1
2  101   1  john        0
3  501   3   Tim        1
4  505   5   Tim        1
5  301   4   Tim        1
6  302   1   Bob        1
7  302   3   Bob        0
```

Update :

```
s=df.groupby(['name']).cumcount().add(1).le(1).astype(int)
s
Out[1421]: 
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    0
dtype: int32
```

More Fast

```
df.loc[df.name.drop_duplicates().index,'counter']=1
df.fillna(0)
Out[1430]: 
  Prod Qty  name  counter
0  101   5  john      1.0
1  102   4  john      0.0
2  101   1  john      0.0
3  501   3   Tim      1.0
4  505   5   Tim      0.0
5  301   4   Tim      0.0
6  302   1   Bob      1.0
7  302   3   Bob      0.0
```

Comment: For the group where name is 'john' , counter = 1 only for first observation. For rest of the observation in john group, counter should be 0. I have updated my post with desired output table.

Comment: df.loc method works like a charm.  What I understand here is first all the duplicate names are dropped and then remaining one name is indexed as 1 ? is it correct ?

Comment: @singularity2047 you got it :-)

Comment: @singularity2047 if this is what you need , can you accept it ?

Answer (score 1):

We can just work directly with your dictionary d and loop through to create a new entry.

```
d = {'name': ['john', 'john', 'john', 'Tim', 'Tim', 'Tim','Bob', 'Bob'], 'Prod': ['101', '102', '101', '501', '505', '301', '302', '302'],'Qty': ['5', '4', '1', '3', '5', '4', '1', '3']}
names = set() #store names that have appeared
id = []
for i in d['name']:
    if i in names: #if it appeared add 0
         id.append(0)
    else:
         id.append(1) #add 1 and note that it has appeared
         names.add(i)
d['id'] = id #add entry to your dictionary
df = pandas.DataFrame(data= d)
```

Comment: This is fantastic. gives me exactly what I wanted.